# Store postgres geometry(point, 4326) column from hibernate + java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgis

I have this column defined in postgres 9.4-1204-jdbc4

location geometry(Point,4326)

and i have this pom.xml with these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
   <version>4.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
   <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
   <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and i want to store the data stored in this class:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

@Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)",name="location")
private Point locationPoint;


public void updateLocation(String locationAsString) {
    this.location = locationAsString;
    int separatorPosition = location.indexOf(" ");
    double x_location = Double.parseDouble(location.substring(0,separatorPosition));
    double y_location = Double.parseDouble(location.substring(separatorPosition));
    //this.locationPoint = new Point(x_location, y_location);
     Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(x_location, y_location );


     GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
     this.locationPoint= gf.createPoint( coord );
     this.locationPoint.setSRID(4326);
}
```

but when i try to store the object in db, it always returns me the error:

ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.

I have defined the hibernate dialect this way

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostGIS Geometry saving: "Invalid endian flag value encountered."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215212/postgis-geometry-saving-invalid-endian-flag-value-encountered)

Comment: I've already checked the 'duplicated' solutions, but same happens