# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postgis

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

I have a Spring Boot v1.5 application with Hibernate 5 running a Postgis database. However, I'm having issues with spatial queries, with the exception being `Invalid endian flag value encountered.`. Searching that exception yields me solutions of adding the appropirate SQL Dialect to the properties file. Doing that, as above, yield me the error from the title.

Running the queries directly in `psql` makes them work, so it's not an issue in my Postgis DB itself.

The theme of these questions is always a misspelling, but I can't find what it would be here.

Comment: You need an additional dependency for the `PostgisDialect` if you haven't added that to your pom or build file it will not resolve to a class.

Comment: Doh! Post it as an answer, for posterity sake in case junior devs are googling this later on as well :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using the [`PostgisDialect`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-configuration-dialect)  you will need the [`hibernate-spatial`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial) project on your classpath as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding something like the above to your list of dependencies should include the proper classes.

Answer (score 2):

Change dialect to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6 (with spatial installed as well), I actually didn't need to explicitly specify that I was using Postgis. It's included automatically in

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

if you have `hibernate-spatial` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here is my 2 cent:

The org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect is already deprecated in later version of hibernate, so you may want to switch to something else, like PostgisPG92Dialect,...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Add the following starter dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This has `hibernate-core` in it.

2. Then add the spatial dependency. Caution! Exactly without version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And that's it! This approach doesn't require explicit definition of hibernate dialect and at the same fixes the `Invalid endian flag value encountered` error.