# How to fix "ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered." during saving data in PostgreSQL through Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgis

I was trying to save data into the PostgreSQL through Hibernate but whenever I try to save "Location" field of "Geometry" data type, it gives me

```
ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
```

This error arises only when I'm trying to set Location of Geometry type. If I comment the line `tempStudent.setLocation((Point) geom)`, the record is successfully saved into database. I am not able to understand where I'm getting wrong in saving the Location.

The SQL statement executed by my code:

```
 insert into student (email, first_name, last_name, location) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

The parameter values:

```
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [abc@gmail.com]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [abc1]
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [abc2]
binding parameter [4] as [VARBINARY] - [POINT (7 2)]
```

The solution suggested in [PostGIS Geometry saving: "Invalid endian flag value encountered."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215212/postgis-geometry-saving-invalid-endian-flag-value-encountered) isn't working for me maybe because I'm using newer versions compared to the ones specified in that post. The versions I am using are:

- spring-5.0.8
- hibernate-c3p0-5.4.2
- hibernate-spatial-5.4.2
- jts-1.13
- PostgreSQL 10
- PostGIS Bundle 2.5.2

Student.java

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column (name="location", columnDefinition="geometry(Point,4326)", nullable=true)
    private Point location;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email, int id, Point location) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
                + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }

}
```

CreateStudentDemo.java

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateStudentDemo mgr = new CreateStudentDemo();
        if(args[0].equals("store")) {
            mgr.storeLocation(assemble(args));
        }
    }

    private void storeLocation(String wktPoint) {
        WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
        Geometry geom = null;
        try {
            geom = fromText.read(wktPoint);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a WKT string: "+wktPoint);
        }
        if (!geom.getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Geometry must be a point. Got a " + geom.getGeometryType());
        }

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try {           
            // create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // start a transaction
        session.beginTransaction();

        // Student tempStudent = new Student("Paul1", "Doe1", "paul@luv2code.com", 5, (Point)geom);

        Student tempStudent = new Student();
        tempStudent.setEmail("abc@sac.in");
        tempStudent.setFirstName("Paul1");
        tempStudent.setLastName("Doel1");
        tempStudent.setLocation((Point) geom);

        /*GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
        Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(10,7));
        tempStudent.setLocation(point);*/

        System.out.println(tempStudent.toString());
        System.out.println("Saving the student...");

        session.save(tempStudent);
        System.out.println("Done!");

        // commit transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        factory.close();
    }

    private static String assemble(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=1; i<args.length; i++) {
            builder.append(args[i]).append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/ats</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">shivam</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error trace:

INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
Creating new student object...

```
Student [id=0, firstName=Paul1, lastName=Doel1, email=abc@sac.in, location=POINT (7 2)]
Saving the student...
Hibernate: insert into student (email, first_name, last_name, location) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Jul 15, 2019 10:04:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: XX000
Jul 15, 2019 10:04:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3673)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:700)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.storeLocation(CreateStudentDemo.java:69)
    at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:19)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:309)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: The problem is however, related to the insertion of Location field i.e of Geometry type in PostgreSQL. So you can check if anything is wrongly implemented regarding that.

Comment: Do you solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *why* Hibernate sends the string `POINT (7 2)` as `VARBINARY`, but that is the source of your problem.

If the input is binary, PostGIS expects the geometry to be in the “Extended Well-Known Binary” (EWKB) format, and it fails to parse it, since your data are actually in “Well-Known Text” (WKT) format.

I don't know enough about Hibernate to tell if that is a bug in Hibernate or in your code, but if you manage to get Hibernate to send the point as a `VARCHAR`, it should work as expected.

Comment: I noticed this is the accepted answer. Were you able to follow Laurenz' advice? How did you do it?