# Save to json postgres : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, postgresql, coordinates

I want to json data save to database but first I need to parse JSON data. I did vector type parser but I could not coordinate.

Example : geoJson

`{"coordinates":[-48.287108838558,-15.679686963558],"type":"Point"}`

I saved to vector type.
my Geojson parse code :

```
public class GeoJSON{

 private String type;
private String data;
public String getType() {return type;}
public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}

public String getData() {return data;}
public void setData(String data) { this.data = data; }

 public GeoJSON() {
}

public GeoJSON(JSONObject json) {
    parse(json);
}

public GeoJSON parse(JSONObject json) {
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    json.write(out);
    this.data = out.toString();
    this.type = json.getString("type");

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return this;
}
```

After Mycontroller in insert method :

```
public boolean insert(GeoJSON item)
{

SavegeojsonEntity theEvent = new SavegeojsonEntity();

    boolean success;
    try {
        String vectorType = item.getType();
        EntityManager em = HibernateSpatialJPA.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        theEvent.setVectorType(vectorType);

        if(vectorType.equals("Point"))
        {
            Geometry geom = wktToGeometry(item.getData());
            System.out.println("geomPo "+geom);
            theEvent.setGeom((Point)geom);
        }
        em.persist(theEvent);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        success=true;
        HibernateSpatialJPA.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
 private Geometry wktToGeometry(String wktPoint) {
    WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
    Geometry geom = null;
    try {
        geom = fromText.read(wktPoint);
    } catch (com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not a WKT string:" + wktPoint);
    }
    return geom;
}
```

My SavegeojsonEntity Class :

Point (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;)

```
 private Point geom;
@Basic
@Column(columnDefinition="Geometry",name = "geom", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
public Point getGeom() {return geom;}
public void setGeom(Point geom) {this.geom = geom;}`
```

the method inserts

`System.out.println("geomPo "+geom);
  geomPo = null`

because

`item.getData() value:
"coordinates":[-48.287108838558,-15.679686963558],"type":"Point"`

I want to `item.getData() value :` -48.287108838558,-15.679686963558

This is my stracktrace :

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
at com.springapp.model.SavegeojsonManager.insert(SavegeojsonManager.java:55)
at com.springapp.model.SavegeojsonManager.insert(SavegeojsonManager.java:26)
at com.springapp.mvc.HSpatialController.saveGeoJson(HSpatialController.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.hibernate.spatial.GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.getBinder(GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.java:52)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:305)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:57)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2705)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2959)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3403)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
... 40 more
```

Please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify versions. looks like duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236428/hibernate-persist-failure-with-postgis-geometry]

Comment: Postgresql 9.4 , hibernate 4.1.6. I deleted wktGeometry  method and cascade. I wrote instead of  `JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(item.getData());
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");`  and code output : [33.451172411442,37.889648973942] .     I want to save postgresql column but how ? @sibnick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Alright so after some investigation trough remote desktop we finally did it.

Conclusion was that there were wrong annotation on `SavegeojsonEntity`.

1. Annotations works on fields not on get method
2. There was wrong dialect: instead of:

`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>`

the most appopriate one is

`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>`

And ofcourse this also has to be done to made proper `Point`.

There is something wrong in your GeoJSON

```
    public class GeoJSON{

    private String type;
    private String data;
    private String pointRepresentation;
    public String getType() {return type;}
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}
    public String getPointRepresentation(){return this.pointRepresentation;}

    public String getData() {return data;}
    public void setData(String data) { this.data = data; }

     public GeoJSON() {
    }

    public GeoJSON(JSONObject json) {
        parse(json);
    }

    public GeoJSON parse(JSONObject json) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("coordinates");
        this.type = json.getString("type");
        data = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            data += jsonArray.get(i) + ",";
        }
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
            pointRepresentation = type + "(" + data + ")";
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

and here put pointRepresentation:

```
if(vectorType.equals("Point"))
        {
            Geometry geom = wktToGeometry(item.getPointRepresentation());
            System.out.println("geomPo "+geom);
            theEvent.setGeom((Point)geom);
        }
```

and check the results.

Comment: I did and result `JSONArray[0] not a string.`  and I cant see `System.out.println("geomPo "+geom);` @PawelGlowacz

Comment: I did like you said @PawelGlowacz

Comment: Any improvements ? Now you should have this `Point(-48.287108838558,-15.679686963558)` when you pass to `wktToGeometry` method. And then it should parse as `Point` object. Any new errors ?

Comment: I certainly do as you say. GeoJson class in parse method for I wrote `System.out.println("dataa"+pointRepresentation);`  to check but I can see code output and I still same error . This is error : `JSONArray[0] not a string.` @PawelGlowacz

Comment: Do you have another idea for a solution? @PawelGlowacz

Comment: Please enter to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87068/helpingwithgeo and we can talk

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>`  the change.Thank you for advice @PawelGlowacz